# Logstash: Parse Azure Event Hub Logs

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

Sample `message` from Azure Event Hubs logstash plugin:
https://pastebin.com/b8WnQHug

I would like to have output:

```
{
    "operationName": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/diagnosticLogs/Read",
    "category": "kube-apiserver",
    "ccpNamespace": "5d764286d7481f0001d4b054",
    "resourceId": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/RESOURCEGROUPS/MY-RG/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.CONTAINERSERVICE/MANAGEDCLUSTERS/MY-AKS",
    "properties": {
        "log": "First line from record\n Second line from another record\n  Third line from another record \n etc from another recors",
        "stream": "stderr",
        "pod": "kube-apiserver-8b5b9cd44-khjfk",
        "containerID": "4c2ddb8ba9639ae9c88f728d850d550473eb36f4eb3e1d99c3f052b87cff9357"
    },
    "time": "2019-10-16T13:44:16.0000000Z",
    "Cloud": "Public",
    "Environment": "prod"
}
```

Main fields:

- time ( as timestamp )
- pod ( name of pod field)
- stream ( event type field )
- log ( worst part, log field should be concatenate from other `message.records[]` with same `time` and `containerID` fields )

Elasticsearch has experimental Azure module, here is source code/filter  for logstash:

https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/master/x-pack/modules/azure/configuration/logstash/azure.conf.erb

I dont need such a complexity.

I guess I need:

- split filter for new fields
- date filter for message.records[].timestamp
- "something" to find all `message.records` with same `message.records[].time` and `message.records[].properties.containerID` fields and concatenate `message.records[].properties.log` field

Can anyone help?

Thanks

EDIT: It think I will have to consider also this:
 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html
, altough there will be probably in 90% all multiline logs in single event, there may be a chance that it will be splitted into multiple events.
Another problem is that aggregate does not work at scale ( azure event hub plugin can ), so aggregate will be bottleneck..

Comment: I think you should use Logstash for the ETL part: https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash